# Let $\langle S, \psi \rangle=\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \int_0^n \psi'(x)dx$. Is S a distribution?

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $\langle S, \psi\rangle=\sum_{n \in N} \int_0^n \psi'(x)dx$. Is S a distribution?

I claim that S is not a distribution.

I know that if S was a distribution it would satisfy the following property:

$$|\langle S,\psi\rangle|=C_N \sum_{|\alpha \leq N} \|\partial^\alpha \psi\|_\infty$$

So far I have

$$|\langle S,\psi\rangle|=|\sum_{n \in N} \int_0^n \psi'(x)dx|
=|\sum_{n \in N} \psi(x) -\psi(0)|
=\sum_{n \in N} |\psi(x) -\psi(0)|
\leq \sum_{n \in N} |\psi(x)| + |\psi(0)|$$

Comment: For any $\psi$ with $\psi '=1$ on $[0,1]$ the sum isn't even finite.

Comment: @mathematician At what point can I state that in the proof above?

Comment: What I typed is all you need.

Comment: TeX remark: use `\in` for $\in$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt went astray at this step: 
$$
\left|\sum_{n \epsilon N} \psi(x) -\psi(0)\right| =\sum_{n \epsilon N} |\psi(x) -\psi(0)| \tag{wrong}
$$
The triangle inequality gives $\le$, but this does not help you demonstrate your claim (since you wanted to show the sum on the left is large).

Instead, consider a partial sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^M (\psi(x) -\psi(0)) = \sum_{n=1}^M  \psi(x) - M \psi(0)$$ 
and you'll see the root of trouble: it's $M\psi(0)$. The sum $\sum_{n=1}^M  \psi(x)$ has a limit as $M\to\infty$, since $\psi$ is a test function. But $M\psi(0)$ does not (unless $\psi(0)$ happens to be zero, which it need not be).